# SQL Server: ;WITH x AS - Invalid operation. The connection is closed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My connection string is static and is overridden by multiple processes but the value remains the same. Multiple processes use the above method at different times for different purposes (sometimes purpose can be same or targeting same SQL entity).

I am getting the following error on live server (strong enough) but on local it works properly. The size of live database is more than 33 GB (and will increase day by day). Error is:

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

Here is stack trace:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Rollback()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
>   at WEB.Data.Database.ExecuteCommandToScalar(SqlCommand command, IEnumerable`1 parameters, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>   at WEB.Data.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedureToScalar(SqlCommand command, IEnumerable`1 parameters, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>   at WEB.Data.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedureToScalar(String procedureName, IEnumerable`1 parameters, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>   at Web.SchedulerLibrary.Service.DbService.ExecuteSpToScalar(String spName, List`1 parameters)
>   at Web.SchedulerLibrary.Service.DbService.GetLastProceessedOnProduct(Int64 locationId, String prodName, String merchantName)
>   at Web.SchedulerLibrary.SchedulerLibrary.ExecuteForProduct(Int64 merchantId, Int64 locationId, String merchantName, String prodName, String ipAddress)

My code is:

```
public static object ExecuteCommandToScalar(string commandText, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters = null, IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, bool? isStoredProcedure = false)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText);

    if (command == null) 
        return null;

    if (isStoredProcedure == true)
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    }

    command.LoadParameters(parameters);

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);

            try
            {
               command.Connection = connection;
               command.Transaction = transaction;

               var scalar = command.ExecuteScalar();
               transaction.Commit();

               return scalar;
           }
           catch
           {
               transaction.Rollback();
               throw;
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           connection.Close();
       }
   }
}
```

And below is my stored procedure which causes the error. In this stored procedure, I am trying to get last `CreatedOn` when the product activated on last time. This Stored Procedure call in loop (most of time a loop is about more than 500 count). sometime it works well and some times gives this error.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @CreatedOn NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedOn)
    FROM 
        ProductDetails 
    WHERE
        UserID = @UserId
)
SELECT TOP 1 @CreatedOn = CreatedOn
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 999999999999999999
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, CreatedOn , 103)
                            ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC) AS RId,
         CreatedOn
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              (CASE 
                  WHEN (x.IsActive = 1) 
                     THEN CAST(x.CreatedOn AS VARCHAR) 
                     ELSE '' 
               END) AS CreatedOn
          FROM 
              x 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              x AS y ON x.rn = y.rn + 1
                     AND x.IsActive <> y.IsActive
          WHERE 
              y.IsActive IS NOT NULL

          UNION

          SELECT TOP 1 
              pri.CreatedOn
          FROM 
              ProductDetails pri 
          WHERE
              UserID = @UserId 
          ORDER BY 
              CreatedOn ASC) A
    ORDER BY  
        CreatedOn DESC) B

    SELECT @CreatedOn
END
```

I don't understand where is problem? In code or in stored procedure it self.Cause other stored procedures in same call executes without any issue at all.I spent couple of days on this but couldn't find out the Issue.

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe integer overflow in the TOP clause. Replace that with `TOP 100 PERCENT`. What is the purpose of this anyway? can it not be replaced by a `MAX` aggregate?

Comment: what happens if you run this SQL code in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: @dlatikay Thank you for your quick response.
Yes, I can try TOP 100 PERCENT. Let me check.

Comment: @MatthewWhited it executes properly in SQL Management studio.

Comment: You do not have a catch for the outer TRY.  Is it possible you are throwing an error when you open the connection?  Given that this is an unhandled error message you are getting I would suggest you look there first.

Comment: (both the try/catch and the try/finally are redundant... but that's a different issue.)

Comment: Is the userID passed into the stored proc the same when it is successful and when it times out? Could it be a parameter sniffing issue? You could try using RECOMPILE or set the variable locally again within the stored proc. I would look at rewriting your SQL however, it looks a bit frisky. Know what I am sayin'?

Comment: @all sorry to forgot to write this function call in loop(most of time more than 500 time in a loop) and sometime it works well and sometime it gives above error.

Comment: @JM_I have updated my code to catch for outer TRY. Thank you so much

Comment: I have added Non- Cluster Index on UserID of Productdetail table and problem is solved.still i will have to work on my database through out to set proper non cluster index. But now I can say that Non-Cluster indexes improves performance.I hope this can help somebody.